# Displaying weather with geolocation and API

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I am trying to display current weather by geolocation, using the openweathermap, but I keep getting the error 'data.main is undefined', as I am trying to get the data from this json file:

```
{"coord":{"lon":16.44,"lat":43.51},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":291.15,"pressure":1017,"humidity":68,"temp_min":291.15,"temp_max":291.15},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":2.01,"deg":146.502},"clouds":{"all":0},"dt":1459758600,"sys":{"type":1,"id":5459,"message":0.0285,"country":"HR","sunrise":1459744171,"sunset":1459790713},"id":3190261,"name":"Split","cod":200}
```

I don't understand how should I grab the desired parameters from the page, such as temperature, wind, humidity...any help appreciated

Here's the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/g19nw53k/

Comment: `weather` is an array.

Comment: What is the runtime value of `data` when you get that error?

Comment: could you perhaps show me in a fiddle? I'm trying with a dot notation but still gives me an error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is an asynchronous function. This means that when you call:

```
var api = 'http://api.openwe...?lat=' + lat + ...;
```

variables `lat` and `long` are still undefined, therefore the API returns response with code `404` where there's no `data.main.temp` as you expect.

You can make the API call after the async function is resolved, see updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/foc7weg2/ (although it might return 401 error because of wrong app id)

Comment: Thank you very much. On my way to learn about asynchronous functions and fetchApi...